# How to get the region shown in the image ?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

i want to get the red region as specified in the image below :

[image: region shown in red]

**remember that the red region that is shown in the image is just for clarification , it is not present in original image** , below is the original image attached :

[image: Original Image]

**i also have the iris point in this region, i already got that point ,** if that point can help me so i can share that image too.

can someone help me in this .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific image, let's call it `BW`, you can find the center region as:

```
BWnoBorder= imclearborder(BW); %# remove the white that touches the border
OnlyCenter = bwareaopen(BWnoBorder,1000); %# remove all small pixel areas
```

Answer (score 0):

A robust method might be the [snake](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~sczhu/papers/region_competition_pami.pdf%E2%80%8E) region growing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you thresholded the eye illuminated by IR or something. To answer your question or even to ask it correctly you have to show a number of images to evaluate the stability and noise in eye socket regions. Otherwise one can come up with a solution that works for the image above but not in general.

For example, I can invert your image, get the largest Connected Component (the dark region) and [erode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#cv2.erode) it till it becomes thin, see below. It is easy to get an ellipse from this binary mask but will it work in general case with your noisy input?

[image]

A good thing to start is to say what do you expect to find. Say you are looking for an eye, dark surrounding area and a bright skin tone - make it 3 Mixed models that settle simultaneously in the [EM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) fashion. Provide some shape priors to increase accuracy. think about other visual cues such as specs on the iris, saccades, FA from blinks, etc.